# User Profile Search Results on Google

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search

When searching your name on Google, the first few results that are listed are mostly your profiles on Linkedin, Twitter, etc.

I would like to know that when a user creates a new account on Linkedin for example, how is Google made aware of this page of this new user in particular? Is it through the use of google analytics on the page or is the link published to Google explicitly in some global directory?

This question has intrigued me quite a bit. Any light on this would be of great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know answer of this question, you need to know how Google crawler work. Kindly refer this page first: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70897#1

Google crawler finds new pages by visiting those links on already indexed pages and adds those newly crawled pages to their search index.

Now, when you create new profile on linkedin, the link of your newly created profile will definitely added in group you joined, your friend's list or any other places of linkedin website. When google crawler visit those page, they will find your profile link and will index them.